# entityManager createNativeQuery auto commit

Tags: hibernate, jpa, commit, entitymanager, flush

```
try {
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            // insert in process_loan_ledger
                this.saveProcessLoanLedger(ledgerMonth);
                // insert into loan_ledger from process_loan_ledger
                this.saveLoanLedger(ledgerMonth);
                // delete loans from loan_ledger where emp code like '9-99%'
                this.deleteFromLoanLedger(ledgerMonth);
                // insert into Emp ledger from loan ledger
                this.saveLoansIntoEmpLedger(ledgerMonth, role);
            tx.commit();
           }
    } catch (Exception x) {
               -----rollback-------
            }
        } finally {
            -----entity manager closed-------
        }
```

Above code i am using to insert or update in DB.
Each function contains 2-5 createNativeQuery.
It seems that after every native query it auto commits.
But i there is exception in any query there is no rollback but throws exception like:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

I want to commit when i am doing tx.commit(); otherwise rollback.

One of those methods:

```
public void saveProcessLoanLedger(Integer ledgerMonth) {
    try {
        /**
         * truncate PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER
         */
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER").executeUpdate();

        /**
         * insert into PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER
         */
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT"
                + " INTO PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER"
                + " SELECT NULL AS \"ID\" ,"
                + "  :ledgMonth AS LEDGER_MONTH ,"
                + "  LOANS.BAL ,"
                + "  LOANS.CUM_INTR ,"
                + "  LOANS.GRACE_PERIOD,"
                + "  LOANS.INSTALL ,"
                + "  LOANS.INSTALL_NO ,"
                + "  LOANS.INT ,"
                + "  LOANS.IS_CUR_STATUS ,"
                + "  LOANS.PRINCIPAL ,"
                + "  LOANS.LOANTYPES_ID ,"
                + "  LOANS.EMPLOYEES_ID ,"
                + "  LOANS.LOAN_UID ,"
                + "  'System' AS CREATED_BY ,"
                + "  'System' AS UDPATED_BY ,"
                + "  LOANS.BAL ,"
                + "  TRUNC((LOANS.BAL * LOAN_TYPES.INTEREST_RATE) / 1200.0, 2) AS CALCULATED_INT, "
                + "  :currentTimeStamp ,"
                + "  :currentTimeStamp "
                + " FROM"
                + " LOANS"
                + " INNER JOIN LOAN_TYPES"
                + " ON (LOANS.LOANTYPES_ID = LOAN_TYPES.\"ID\")"
                + " WHERE IS_CUR_STATUS = 0").setParameter("currentTimeStamp", new java.sql.Timestamp(currentTimeStamp.getTime())).setParameter("ledgMonth", ledgerMonth).executeUpdate();

        /**
         * update into PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER
         */
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER"
                + " SET INSTALL = LEAST(INSTALL, BAL)"
                + " WHERE GRACE_PERIOD = 0"
                + " AND IS_CUR_STATUS = 0").executeUpdate();

        entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER"
                + " SET INT = LEAST(INT, CUM_INTR)"
                + " WHERE GRACE_PERIOD = 0"
                + " AND INSTALL = 0"
                + " AND IS_CUR_STATUS = 0").executeUpdate();

        //check for action 6 loan if value = 1 then int is 0
        try {
            Integer action6Loan = Integer.parseInt((String) entityManager.createNativeQuery("select value from PAYROLL_SETTINGS where id = 'Action_6_loan'").getSingleResult());
            if (action6Loan == 1) {
                entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER "
                        + "SET CALCULATED_INT = 0 "
                        + "WHERE EMPLOYEES_ID IN "
                        + "  (SELECT ID "
                        + "   FROM "
                        + "    ("
                        + this.getAction6ForPRL()
                        + "    ) "
                        + "  )").setParameter("ledgMonth", ledgerMonth).executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
        }

        // guaranter loan interest = 0 
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("update PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER set CALCULATED_INT = 0 where LOAN_UID like '%:G%'").executeUpdate();

        //action 8 set install=0, int=0, CALCULATED_INT=0
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("update PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER "
                + "set install=0, int=0, CALCULATED_INT=0 "
                + "WHERE EMPLOYEES_ID IN "
                + "  (SELECT ie.id "
                + "  FROM EMPLOYEES ie "
                + "  INNER JOIN "
                + "    (SELECT EMPLOYEES_ID, "
                + "      ACTION "
                + "    FROM "
                + "      (SELECT ep.EMPLOYEES_ID, "
                + "        CASE "
                + "          WHEN es.ACTION IS NULL "
                + "          THEN ep.ACTION "
                + "          ELSE ES.ACTION "
                + "        END ACTION "
                + "      FROM EMP_PAYSCALES ep "
                + "      LEFT JOIN EMP_STATUS es "
                + "      ON (ep.EMPLOYEES_ID = es.EMPLOYEES_ID "
                + "      AND es.ledger_month = :ledgMonth) "
                + "      ) "
                + "    WHERE ACTION IN (8) "
                + "    ) ies ON (ie.ID   = IES.EMPLOYEES_ID) "
                + "  )").setParameter("ledgMonth", ledgerMonth).executeUpdate();

        entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER"
                + " SET INT = CALCULATED_INT"
                + " WHERE LOAN_UID = 'LB'"
                + " AND IS_CUR_STATUS = 0").executeUpdate();

        entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER"
                + " SET BAL = BAL - INSTALL,"
                + " CUM_INTR = CUM_INTR - INT + CALCULATED_INT"
                + " WHERE IS_CUR_STATUS = 0").executeUpdate();

        entityManager.createNativeQuery("delete from process_loan_ledger where (bal=0 or bal is null) and (cum_intr=0 or cum_intr is null) and (INSTALL=0 or INSTALL is null) and (INT=0 or INT is null)").executeUpdate();

        //delete employees who is 5
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE "
                + "FROM process_loan_ledger "
                + "WHERE employees_id IN "
                + "  (SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEES_ID) FROM PROCESS_LOAN_LEDGER "
                + "  MINUS "
                + "  SELECT ie.id "
                + "  FROM EMPLOYEES ie "
                + "  INNER JOIN "
                + "    (SELECT EMPLOYEES_ID, "
                + "      ACTION "
                + "    FROM "
                + "      (SELECT ep.EMPLOYEES_ID, "
                + "        CASE "
                + "          WHEN es.ACTION IS NULL "
                + "          THEN ep.ACTION "
                + "          ELSE ES.ACTION "
                + "        END ACTION "
                + "      FROM EMP_PAYSCALES ep "
                + "      LEFT JOIN EMP_STATUS es "
                + "      ON (ep.EMPLOYEES_ID = es.EMPLOYEES_ID "
                + "      AND es.ledger_month = :ledgMonth) "
                + "      ) "
                + "    WHERE ACTION NOT IN (5) "
                + "    ) ies ON (ie.ID   = IES.EMPLOYEES_ID) "
                + "  )").setParameter("ledgMonth", ledgerMonth).executeUpdate();

        msg = new StringBuilder().append(msg).append("Loan successfully processed<br>").toString();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        msg = new StringBuilder().append(msg).append("Loan process failed<br>").toString();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
at net.divineit.titas.daos.SalaryProcessingDao.salaryProcess(SalaryProcessingDao.java:109)
at net.divineit.titas.services.SalaryProcessingService.salaryProcess(SalaryProcessingService.java:12)
at net.divineit.titas.controllers.SalaryProcessingControllers.saveLedgers(SalaryProcessingControllers.java:221)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at net.divineit.titas.filter.UrlRoleFilter.doFilter(UrlRoleFilter.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  exception message::  Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code of those methods. Show us the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Wait, you're using Spring, and you manage transactions by yourself? Why? Let Spring handle transactions declaratively. Read the documentation. Also, don't ignore exceptions like you're doing. You can't just continue as if nothing happened if executing a query throws an exception. I don't know why you think the transaction is already committed. It's not. On the contrary: it's marked as rollbackOnly. Meaning: the only thing you can do with that transaction is to rollback it.

Comment: used manual transaction in whole project. Changing in this time is difficult for this module now. From functions i am throwing exception and catch in above code. But also the same is happening.

Comment: @Check keep on using such kind of inappropriate design is just going to increase technical debt of your project.  And, it is not difficult to fix it: Just make sure correct transaction boundary is applied (e.g. around your controller, or service etc), and remove those txn handling code in your DAO/Repository.

Comment: is there any other thing to do without changing trnasaction in this way?